# Does devise support multiple accounts with the same email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cakephp, devise

I am looking into moving my authentication in a CakePHP app to Rails Devise. However, our site uses usernames as a unique identifier rather than email, as often families use the same email address on multiple accounts.

By default it looks like Devise uses email as a unique identifier - is it possible to have multiple accounts with the same email address when using Devise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set

`config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]`

in your *device.rb*. You may also use the following settings to make login more solid

```
config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :username ]
config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :username ]
```